# I can't work out what this switch is for

Tags: electrical, walls

In my new home, on onr 1 wall, there is the switch shown below.
[image: Unknown switch]

I would have assumed it was for an electric fireplace, but there are no signs around it at all.
[image: Bare wall around switch]

what is this switch most likely for?
Please note it wasn't us who splattered pain all over it.

Comment: Where is the home located (that is, what country)?  What is that vertical rectangle to the left of the switch?  Is the cover to a recessed slot?

Comment: @wallyk I am in England, and the rectangle is for a fuse.

Comment: What size of fuse (I mean amperes)?

Comment: I'm not sure from the top of my head. I'll have to have a look after work. Thanks.

Comment: Check all of the receptacles to see if any of them are switched.

Comment: @ArchonOSX the switch seems to be in the off position and everything in the house seems to be working fine. I haven't had anything in the outlets of that room yet though.

Comment: Well if it switches an receptacle, then it would be located in that room. Usually this is done to provide a switch for a lamp in a room without a ceiling light. But I see in your picture you have a ceiling light. With the integral fuse it seems as though it may be for a specific function other than general lighting or power.

Comment: Usually when I see this sort of switch in a living room it is for an electric fire place, but there is nothing at all there.

Comment: @ArchonOSX. In the UK, *all* receptacles (except rarely in very old unmodernised houses) have individual switches built into the coverplate - you never need a separate switch. Separate fused switches are normally only used in the UK for high-power (e.g. > 3kW) and/or hard-wired (non plugged) appliances like heating systems, ovens and so on. Lighting switches are unfused and placed near shoulder height.

Comment: While you're at it, you might want to remove the cover just to make sure it's even hooked up to anything at all. Stranger things have happened...

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick  Thanks for the info on the UK. Interesting that the fuse circuits at the switch location.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, switches with fuses are normally used for high-power and/or permanently wired appliances such as heating systems, electric-showers, ovens and so on.

It is possible your consumer unit (AKA distribution board or fusebox) has a circuit labelled for that outlet. I would check that and try to match up every circuit.

A normal small UK home might have

- downstairs ring-main
- upstairs ring main
- downstairs lighting
- upstairs lighting
- central heating
- kitchen (electric oven, hob etc)
- electric shower
- garage

If there is something extra it might be associated with your mystery-switch.

Fused switches are usually located right next to the appliance they control e.g. next to oven, next to immersion heater.

The fused switch seems to be in an awkward location for anything outside the room (e.g. outside floodlights, immersion heater on other side of wall).

Perhaps a voltage or metal detector will detect that the switched live wire leads to a spot on the wall where an electric fire has been removed?